# Is Ext.NET a server side library?

Tags: extjs, ext.net

This is a little "vague" question. I would like to know how the Ext.NET library works. I know it is a "wrapper" on top of extjs, but my question is: Is Ext.NET usable by server code and not via "complicated" javascript client side code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Quote](http://www.ext.net/):

> Ext.NET is an open source ASP.NET
>   (WebForm + MVC) component framework
>   integrating the cross-browser Sencha
>   Ext JS JavaScript Library.

So it is a collection of server side controls for ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC which generate HTML markup and javascript based on the Extjs library. So to answer your question, yes, it is usable by server side code but without at least basic knowledge of the client side part I am afraid that you won't get very far.